# Break up a datetime into a date and time select with Simple Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, materialize

I'm using Materialize css framework to format my forms. I now run into the problem that I want to use the date & timepicker that comes with it to populate a single datetime fields. Is there a way to break that single field into two seperate inputs?

I'm rendering the field like this:

```
.col.s6
  = f.input :date, as: :date, html5: true, input_html: {class: 'datepicker current-date', type: 'date'}
  = f.input :date, as: :time, html5: true, input_html: {class: 'datepicker current-date', type: 'date'}
```

This works, only uses the same variable name, overwriting the paramater. Anyway to define that these fields need to concatenated?

Comment: maybe you need to remove `as: :string`.

Comment: copied wrong code, sorry, check again please.